# Download a directory from ftp using perl

Tags: perl, ftp

Is it possible to download folders from any of repository in ftp using perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Net::Lite::FTP](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aLite%3a%3aFTP), the synopsis of the module seems to do exactly what you need. I've copied it here for reference:

```
use Net::Lite::FTP;
my $tlsftp=Net::Lite::FTP->new();
$tlsftp->open("ftp.tls.pl","21");
$tlsftp->user("user");
$tlsftp->pass("password");
$tlsftp->cwd("pub");
my $files=$tlsftp->nlst("*.exe");
foreach $f (@files) {
    $tlsftp->get($f);
};
```

Comment: I need do download the folders only from that array. The get method is not working while downloading the folders